# best way to access struct variable from header files that defined in c file

Tags: c

I declared a struct in `main.c` file and i have functions in `func1.c func2.c func1.h func2.h` files.

`main.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "func1.h"
#include "func2.h"

    struct mystruct{
    someting
    };

main(){
 struct mystruct var ={...};
 myfunc(var);
}
```

`func1.h`:

```
void myfunc(struct mystruct);
```

And definition is in `func1.c`. Similar for func2 files. I got compilation errors, it  is obvious that problem is header file dont have declaration of `mystruct` and so cant use it.
So what is the way to overcome that problem? Adding a new header file for struct or using extern keyword what i read. What is approprite choice i couldnt figure out at that point.

Comment: Yes, put the struct definition in a header file, maybe `main.h`.

Comment: but there is `redefinition of struct` error when doing it. it looks both header files adding same struct to `main.c`

Answer (score 0):

```
struct mystruct{
//something
};
```

Should be defined in a header file which all your c files that need it has access to.

mytypes.h

```
#ifndef mytypes_h
#define mytypes_h

struct mystruct{
 int something;
};

#endif
```

func1.h

```
#ifndef func1_h
#define func1_h

#include "mytypes.h"
void myfunc(struct mystruct);

#endif
```

func1.c

```
#include "func1.h"
void myfunc(struct mystruct){
 //do soemthing with struct
}
```

Then your main can include func1.h which already mytypes.h

main.c

```
#include "func1.h"

int main(){
 
}
```

Comment: I did it but now i got **redefinition of struct** error. I add `types.h` header both `func1.h fun2.h` and added these headers to `main.c` and getting this error with some additional errors.

Comment: @hepl You may want to look into [include guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) in this case. Best to have include guards in any header file, but in this case specifically, having one in `types.h` should suffice I guess.

Comment: @hepl As Oskar suggested, you can use include guards. Look at my edited answer and use those.

Comment: Please at the beginning use any modern IDE that provides automatic features in preventing types re-definition and auto-type guarding

Comment: @Tomas My IDE would have added guards; however, I didn't use an IDE when typing this answer out. I assumed the user's IDE would have added include guards. Maybe it did and they erased it thinking it was unnecessary. Or maybe they didn't use an IDE and just used a text editor. I'm not sure.

Comment: @Yuumi I was reffering to OP not your answer :)

Comment: Thanks, i tried it and it is enough to just add to `types.h` header file.

Comment: @hepl You should add it to all your header files.